# JavaScript - WebSocket send() method not executing

Tags: javascript, java, java-websocket

I have written a simple client-server app where the client uses WebSocket in Javascript and the server uses the Jetty library for WebSocket. This is the server code that handles messages from the client:

```
@OnWebSocketConnect
    public void onConnect(Session session) {

        System.out.println("Connected");
    }

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
```

and this is the code of the client when sending messages:

```
function Search() {
"use strict";
sender = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
sender.send("Hello server");
sender.close();
}
```

So when I call the "Search" function the output of the server is this:

[Server output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHjFY.png)

Which means line `sender.send("Hello server");` was not executed.

But when I insert `alert("connected");` after `sender = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");` this is the new output:

[New output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3EwZ.png)

I have read the documentation about `send()` but it does not address this issue. Do you have any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 3):

You're not waiting for the connection to actually open. The reason it works with `alert()` is that you gain time for the socket to finish connecting.

Try this:

```
sender = new WebSocket(...)

sender.onopen = function() {
  sender.send('Hello server')
  sender.close()
}
```

The function you set as `onopen` will be executed when the connection is ready to send and receive data.

#### Why?

When you do `new WebSocket()`, Javascript doesn't wait until the socket is fully connected before moving on to the next line of code. The connection is just scheduled to happen.

This is **unlike Java**, the other language you're using, where execution usually blocks before moving on.

In your piece, you call `close()` immediately after creating the socket. This won't connect and then disconnect. The connection will never complete, since you only *scheduled* a connection and immediately cancelled it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I have used this method before but it seems the send() function only works inside onopen(). For example, when executing this code:

function Search() {
    "use strict";
    sender = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
    sender.onopen=function() {
        sender.send("Hello Server!");
    };
    sender.send("Hello again!");
    sender.close();
}

the lines after onopen() should execute since the connection is established, but that's not the case. Are messages supposed to be sent only from inside onopen()?

Thanks again

Comment: Slightly late but if someone is seeing this later and wondering the same question as @Captain_Rookie yes `.onopen()` is async so it executes whenever it has to when all of the conditions are met. (over simplification but you should get the point)